# How to refresh data from XmlListModel in intervals or when data is changed?

Tags: xml, qml, reload

I have seen others use the "onSourceChanged: reload();" signal in XmlListModel, but I can't find any information about it (and it's not working for me).
The xml file is updated fast ( 1 or 2 times a second).
I have also tried with my own xml file and manually editing it, but no success.

How can I update the ListView/XmlListModel so my application always shows the correct data? (That be in intervals or when sources has changed).

My XmlListModel file (ICDModel.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

XmlListModel {

    source: "http://192.168.1.103:89/FunctionGenerator/FuncGen1.xml"
    query: "/Component/Signals/Signal"

    onSourceChanged: reload();

    XmlRole { name: "Name"; query: "@Name/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "Description"; query: "@Description/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "Value"; query: "@Value/string()"; isKey: true }
}
```

The ListView inside main.qml

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 10
    model: ICDModel2 {}
    delegate: contactDelegate
    highlight: highlightBar
    highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false
    focus: true
}
```

Finally the delegate (also inside main.qml)

```
Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            id: wrapper
            height: 40; width: parent.width
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + Name }
                Text { text: '<b>Description:</b> ' + Description }
                Text { text: '<b>Value:</b> ' + Value }

            }
            states: State {
                name: "Current"
                when: wrapper.ListView.isCurrentItem
                PropertyChanges { target: wrapper; x: 20 }
            }
            transitions: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; duration: 200 }
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: mouse_area1
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: false
                onClicked: {
                    wrapper.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you change the source? I only see a static source so the "onSourceChanged" signal will not be called!?

Comment: You are right, @Xander . Can't believe I didn't realize "onSourceChanged" is only being called when the actual source url is changed, and not the values in gathered from the source. (Stupid mistake). A friend found a solution, so I should close this question somehow. Thanks!

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it as the answer (if someone else has a similar problem). :)

Comment: So what was your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As this issue took me quite some time to tackle this issue and the original poster did not bother to provide his solution, I'll show how I could workaround this problem:

I added a random attribute to my source and use a timer to reload the XmlListModel in a given interval.

```
Timer {
  id: xmlContentReloader
  repeat: true
  interval: 1000 * 60 // Check once a minute
  onTriggered: {
      xmlModel.source = "http://<host>/servermessage.xml?requestid=" + Math.random() * 9999
      xmlModel.reload()
  }
```

}

XmlListModel {
      id: xmlModel

```
  source: {

      return "http://<host>/servermessage.xml?requestid=" + Math.random() * 9999
  }
  query: "/item"

  XmlRole { name: "storeVersion"; query: "CurrentVersion/string()" }
  XmlRole { name: "motd"; query: qsTr("en-US") + "/string()" }

  onStatusChanged: {

     if (status == XmlListModel.Ready) {

        var storeName = ""
        if (!xmlContentReloader.running) xmlContentReloader.start()
```

.
.
.